# Append value into an existing row

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm trying to create a video player and I would like to be able to save the data of the ***mediaPlayer.position()*** in a QTableWidget.
Video Player Program:

[image: Video Player Program]

However, I'm stuck.I try to insert values in an empty row but nothing is displayed.

```
        def addSub(self):
        row = self.table.rowCount()
        self.table.insertRow(row)
```

This is how I create a new row.
And I want that when I press shortcut like "Ctrl+F" or "Ctrl+T" (set up beforehand), datas goes on this empty row like this

```
    def startHere(self):
        newStart = self.mediaPlayer.position()
        row = self.table.rowCount()
        self.table.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(newStart)))
    
    def endHere(self):
        newEnd = self.mediaPlayer.position()
        row = self.table.rowCount()
        self.table.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(newEnd)))
```

Comment: You don't really need the `addSub` method. Just do the `insertRow` in `startHere` and then do `rowCount() - 1` in `endHere`.

Comment: I need the ’addSub’ method I want to write in the last cells of my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the item for a row that doesn't exist.

Suppose you have an empty table, you run `addSub` and then `startHere`:

```
    def addSub(self):
        row = self.table.rowCount()
        # row is 0
        self.table.insertRow(row)
        # inserts a row at index 0, as indexes are always 0-based

    def startHere(self):
        newStart = self.mediaPlayer.position()
        row = self.table.rowCount()
        # you just created a row, so the line above returns 1
        self.table.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(newStart)))
        # row 1 does not exist, so setItem is ignored
```

The solution is to subtract 1 before using it on `setItem`:

```
    def startHere(self):
        newStart = self.mediaPlayer.position()
        row = self.table.rowCount() - 1
                                   ^^^^
        self.table.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(newStart)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work. Currently, I had the issue you solved, I tried printing in which row I'am, and now it's good. But my data still not displayed. I tried to overwrite another row to test it, and it deleted the data inside but it doesn't write anything instead.

Comment: Ok now it's working I don't know why ... I think I just forgot something